# Meaning of "standalone" in gnuplot "set terminal epslatex"

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot

I'm trying the `epslatex` terminal in gnuplot. Surfing around the internet I've found lot of examples where the `term` is `set` with the command line

```
set terminal epslatex size 9cm,7cm color colortext standalone header
```

Does this add some benefit to my plot or does it change something if I don't put the `standalone` command?

EDIT: Also what's the difference between `color` and `colortext`? Do I need both of them?

Comment: Please read documentation. Copypaste from there: If using the `standalone` mode a complete LaTeX header is added to the
 LaTeX file; and "-inc" is added to the filename of the eps file.
 The `standalone` mode generates a TeX file that produces
 output with the correct size when using dvips, pdfTeX, or VTeX.
 The default, `input`, generates a file that has to be included into a
 LaTeX document using the \input command.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm new with this terminal and I was very confused. Where did you find this documentation? On the [SourceForge](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node373.html) official explanation of the `terminal` the last (very clear and helpful) part of your comment wasn't so explicit. Thx anyway!

Comment: Type in gnuplot `help epslatex`, or go to http://gnuplot.info and read it there.

Comment: In general, using the embedded `help` documentation should be the first place to look for help with gnuplot. But I remember wondering the same thing about `epslatex` when I first saw it. This is an important terminal option as it significantly affects how you use the output produced. The `standalone` explanation from the `help` documentation is on the 6th or 7th screen of text from `help epslatex`. A new user may not find it easily, or even know to use `help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The `epslatex` terminal

The `epslatex` terminal is the best of two worlds.  It generates output for the *graphical* parts of your plot as encapsulated PostScript (to an `.eps` file) and output for the *text* parts as LaTeX (to a `.tex` file).  The vector graphics ability of LaTeX is very limited (the allowed angles are particularly annoying), and gnuplot's typesetting ability will never compare to LaTeX.  By using the `epslatex` terminal, you are letting gnuplot do its magic with vector graphics as PostScript and letting LaTeX do its magic with the words, stylized text, mathematical equations, etc.

There are two basic ways to use it: either on its own (`standalone`), or as a part of another document (`input`).  You specify which mode you want to use with one of these two terminal options.  The default (if you use neither keyword) is `input`.

### Mode: `standalone`

The `standalone` mode will generate a LaTeX file that is a **complete document**.  The `.tex` file it generates will contain a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  You can send this `.tex` file directly to LaTeX and get a document containing *only your plot*.

A `standalone` example in gnuplot (I'll call the file `example1.gp`):

```sh
set terminal epslatex standalone
set output "example1.tex"
plot sin(2*x)/x title '$y=\frac{\sin 2x}{x}$'
```

Notice that the output file has the `.tex` extension (instead of an `.eps` extension).  Building this with gnuplot

```
$ gnuplot example1.gp
```

creates two files, `example1.tex` (the standalone LaTeX document) and `example1-inc.eps` (the EPS vector graphics part).  Somewhere in `example1.tex` is `\includegraphics{example1-inc}` which includes `example1-inc.eps` into the LaTeX document.  gnuplot has automatically configured all the sizes for you.

You can send this `example1.tex` directly to LaTeX.  I will use `pdflatex`:

```
$ pdflatex example1
```

(The `.tex` extension is implied.) This generates `example1.pdf`, the final document combining both parts.  It looks something like this:

[image: standalone example output]

That font should look familiar, as it is the default LaTeX font.  Notice too that the equation has been processed by LaTeX rather than gnuplot.  (Look at the code in the original `.gp` file above.)

### Mode: `input` (default)

Typically you would want to use `epslatex` when you are writing a paper in `LaTeX` and you want to include some plot in your paper.  You don't want the plot to be a separate document, but a part of the paper.  This is the mode used with the `input` terminal option, or when neither option is given, since it is the default.

For example, here is the gnuplot:

```sh
set terminal epslatex
set output "example2.tex"
plot sin(2*x)/x title '$y=\frac{\sin 2x}{x}$'
```

gnuplot builds `example2.tex` and `example2.eps`.  You can `\input` the `example2.tex` into your LaTeX document.  I usually put it inside a `\resizebox` like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text                        

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!h]\centering
\resizebox{!}{5cm}{\input{example2}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Run this through LaTeX and you get something that looks like:

[image: input example output]

---

*Addendum:* Since the output is going to two places, you can choose to enable color output to each of those two places: `color` for the EPS part and `colortext` for the LaTeX part.

Comment: Thank you so much, the documentation online is really confusing, you have been so clear! So helpful!